# Why is the result of this JavaScript code "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, function, logging, scope, output

I am trying to figure out why the result of this Javascript code in the browser's console window is undefined? Shouldn't it be "outside"?

```
var text = 'outside';
function logIt(){
    console.log(text);
    var text = 'inside';
};
logIt();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a result of "variable hoisting". (See http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting.)

To make the code behave as you expect, you need to either assign the variable within the function scope or pass it as an argument to the function:

```
var logIt = function (){
    var text = 'outside';
    console.log(text);
    text = 'inside';
};
logIt();
```

or

```
var text = 'outside';
var logIt = function (txtArg){
    console.log(txtArg);
    var text = 'inside';
};
logIt(text);
```

Comment: No, it won't. The code behaves like it does because of variable hoisting, not because of function hoisting.

Comment: The reference which you have given is 404

Answer (score 4):

In JavaScript, variables are "hoisted" to the top of the function. That is, unlike some other languages (such as C), a variable declared within a function is within scope *throughout* the function. So the compiler sees your function like this:

```
function logIt(){
    var text;
    console.log(text);
    text = 'inside';
} // <-- no semicolon after a function declaration
```

When you declare `text` as a local variable inside `logIt`, it shadows the variable in the outer scope. And when a variable is declared, it is initialized to undefined. That's why undefined gets printed.

If you want to keep `text` in the outer scope, just leave off the `var` declaration inside the function.

```
var text = 'outside';
function logIt(){
    console.log(text); // logs 'outside' now
    text = 'inside';
}
logIt();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your placement of console.log(text) is in the wrong place :)

But seriously, this is Javascript variable hoisting. http://goo.gl/0L8h5D

This:

```
var text = 'outside'
logIt = function () {
  console.log(text);
  var text = 'inside';
}
logIt();
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
var text                    // hoisted to top of scope; text is undefined
text = 'outside'            // text is now assigned in place
logIt = function () {
  var text;                 // hoisted to top of scope; text is undefined
  console.log(text);        // spits out undefined
  text = 'inside';          // text is now assigned in place.
}
logIt();
```

To avoid these kind of issues, get in the habit of declaring all your var's at the top of a scope block.

```
var text = 'outside'
logIt = function() {
  var text = 'inside'
  console.log(text)
}
logIt()
```

If your intent was to spit out 'outside', then you should use a different identifier name inside the logIt function.

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding the variable text. To get the answer you are looking for take away var from 4th line.

The reason is that inside the function there is a variable called text from the parent scope or global scope and you are changing it then disposing of it as you leave the function.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable `text` once. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1y46rmrg/)

```
var text = 'outside';
function logIt(){
    console.log(text);
     text = 'inside';
};
logIt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Global+Local: An extra complex Case

```
var x = 5;

(function () {
    console.log(x);
    var x = 10;
    console.log(x); 
})();
```

This will print out undefined and 10 rather than 5 and 10 since JavaScript always move variable declarations (not initializations) to the top of the scope, making the code equivalent to:

```
var x = 5;

(function () {
    var x;
    console.log(x);
    x = 10;
    console.log(x); 
})();
```

from this answer [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)